# User account activation, e-mail confirmation, and invitations with Passport / Node.Js

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, email-validation, user-accounts

I want to set up 3 things for my user authentication system running on Passport / Neo4J:

1) Manual user account activation (so that admin does it);

2) Invite-only account creation;

3) E-mail confirmation of account before activation;

I was wondering if you knew of any easy-to-use Passport plugins for it (I haven't found any myself, but also want your recommendations) and also – what would be the best way to implement it (maybe you've already done / seen it, so you could share the code?)

Thank you!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Found this question looking for the exact same things.

Comment: @Alex Neo4J graph database

Comment: ok, not really relevant as you're using Neo4J, but in my app (I use mongoose) I used this, and found it very helpful https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-email-address-manager

Comment: I recently did this using Mongoose for a client and waiting on getting permission to open source it. I'm sure it will be of some use, I'll update later.

Answer (score 3):

Disclosure: I have never worked with Neo4j, so I am unaware of the specifics but I would accomplish this in the following way:

You can write up some simple queries that insert a users information(ex. username, password, email etc.) to your database upon registration. Then, send the user an email using something like [nodemailer](http://www.nodemailer.com/) in which it states that he has been registered and is awaiting confirmation.

Among the user information that you have stored you should have a column where you store the account status(verified or not verified). You can then write up a small webpage for retrieving all the accounts from your database where `verified=false`, and confirm the ones that you want by setting `verified` to `true`, after which the user would receive an email the user telling him that he can now use your service.

As for invite-only registration, I would have a special table with "registration codes" that would be generated and inserted into that table when a user invites someone. The one who was invited would then receive a link with the code, and upon clicking it the server would check if the code exists in the database, and if it does would allow the user to create an account.

I realize that this is a broad answer, but there are many ways to accomplish what you're looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Someone  was having a go at it with Drawbridge, but the build is failing...https://www.npmjs.org/package/drawbridge

I'm Looking for the same thing.

Comment: I implemented passport manually in the end. Check out http://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus